# Angular 5. Why does the provider require a component. InjectorError

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular5

made a small service which will update the display of some data when authorizing and logging out the user (showing and hiding menu items and pictures)

CODE

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { FilmComponent } from '../film/film.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service';


@Injectable()
export class UpdateDataService {
  constructor(private app: AppComponent, private film: FilmComponent, private user: UserService) {}

  updateWhenAuthorized() {
    console.log('user_authorized');
    this.app.current_user_avatar = this.user.getUSer().Avatar;
    this.app.user_authorized = true;
    this.app.show_favorite = true;
    this.app.IsAutentification = false;
    this.film.current_user_avatar = this.user.getUSer().Avatar;
    this.film.showElseNeedLoginForCommentBlock = false;
  }

  updateWhenLogout() {
    console.log('user_logout');
    this.app.user_authorized = false;
    this.app.show_favorite = false;
    this.film.showElseNeedLoginForCommentBlock = true;
  }
}
```

But when I try to log in, I get an error

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for FilmComponent!
```

Here is a link to the github there you can pomomret whole project that would have been clearer
I do not understand. I did the same FilmComponent in the service through the class constructor

https://github.com/Ascolon/electron-angular

Comment: Why have you injected `FilmComponent` as DI? It's a component, not a service. I have never seen injecting a component this way.

Answer (score 2):

Thats not the way you do in Angular (or Typescript).

`constructor()` is for dependency injection. Your **UpdateDataService** is a Singleton, injected in app root component. When you inject it, ** FilmComponent** is probably not initialised.

Better inject that service in component and in service use Subject or BehaviourSubject that emits values as you change them in functions.

In service:

```
  surUsrAvtr = new BehaviourSubject<any>();
  showElse = new BehaviourSubject<any>();

  updateWhenAuthorized() {
    console.log('user_authorized');
    this.app.current_user_avatar = this.user.getUSer().Avatar;
    this.app.user_authorized = true;
    this.app.show_favorite = true;
    this.app.IsAutentification = false;
    this.surUsrAvtr.next(this.user.getUSer().Avatar);
    this.showElse.next(false);
  }

  updateWhenLogout() {
    console.log('user_logout');
    this.app.user_authorized = false;
    this.app.show_favorite = false;
    this.showElse.next(true);
  }
```

And in component subscribe to those:

```
export class FilmComponent implements OnInit {

  urrent_user_avatar: any;
  showElseNeedLoginForCommentBlock: any;

  constructor(private upDataService: UpdateDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.upDataService.surUsrAvtr.subscribe(_ => this.urrent_user_avatar = _);
    this.upDataService.showElse.subscribe(_ => this.showElseNeedLoginForCommentBlock = _);
  }
}
```

The same applies to the AppComponent

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems here:

First:

You are injecting components into services, which does not make sense. As I understand from your code, multiple components need to be updated from the service. So why not use something like Subjects or BehaviorSubject? Your service would emit new values with `subject.next` and components subscribe to these events. See a brief example [here](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc).

Second:

To use a service in angular you must add it to the providers array of the module or component which is using the service. ([see here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services))

I have looked into the Github repo. linked and saw that you are providing the service to each component individually, which means that every component will receive a separate instance of the service. That might cause you problems. 
You probably want to add the services into the provider array of the module. That way all components of that module will receive a singleton instance of that service when injected. See better explanation in the [angular site.](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#singleton-services)